# simple_html_dom's file_get_html not working in loop

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using $html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext; to get the plain text from a website.But if I run this code in some loop because i want access texts from a series of websites ,then for few websites it throws error but same website's plain text gets extracted if I access this function exclusively for that website only

Comment: What are you looping? The $html = file_get_html($url)?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this and let me know if I'm on the right or wrong track with what you want. First I have 2 html files on the server:**

*→ page1.html*

```
<html>
<head><title>HTML Page #1</title></head>
<body><div id="a">A1</div><div id="b">B1</div><div id="b">B1</div></body>
</html>
```

*→ page2.html*

```
<html>
<head><title>HTML Page #2</title></head>
<body><div id="a">A2</div><div id="b">B2</div><div id="b">B2</div></body>
</html>
```

→ Alright, then for your *main PHP page*: (in same folder as .html files)

```
require_once( 'simple_html_dom.php' ); // or w\e the path for your source is

// array to store series of websites:
   $url  = array( './page1.html', './page2.html' );

// array to hold plain-text for later retrieval: (if needed)
   $html = array();

// loop through series of webpages:
   foreach( $url as $key=>$value ) { 

       // get html plain-text for webpage & assign to html array.
          $html[ $key ] = file_get_html( $value )->plaintext; 

       // echo html plain text:
          echo "<br />" . $html[ $key ] . "<br />"; 

   }

   // echo $html[ 0 ]; /* <-- page1.html (if needed) */
   // echo $html[ 1 ]; /* <-- page2.html (if needed) */
```

→ *Output:*

```
HTML Page #1 A1B1B1

HTML Page #2 A2B2B2
```

→ **Does that accomplish what you want the code to do?**